# Some insight about the directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, scalar-fields

Here is the definition of directional derivative given;

$$\lim_{\vec{c} \to \vec{u}} \frac{f(\vec{c} + h\vec{u}) - f(\vec{c})}{h}$$

which gives for a scalar field $f: R^n \to R$, the derivative we get by moving from $\vec{c}$ in the direction of unit vector $\vec{u}$.

But when computing these things, we get different results if we don't use a unit direction. I don't get this part, why is this the case. Isn't $h$ shows the amount we move in the direction $\vec{u}$? So if we give a nonunit vector but same direction, since h goes to $0$, shouldn't we get the same result. After all, we are still moving very very small in the same direction, as long as $h \to 0$.

Comment: But this is about *comparing* the "change in y" to the "change in x". So look in the denominator... there you have $h$. But the corresponding quantity in the numerator is of size $|h|\|u\|$. (It's like saying $x^2/x^2$ and $x^2/x$ should tend to the same limit as $x \to 0$; in fact more or less exactly like this if you imagine that $f(x) = x$).

Comment: Well, we are not changing the x and y independently once we fix a direction but  don't the "change in x" and "change in y" both go to 0, irrespective of what I chose $\vec{u}$ to be, as long as $h \to 0$?

Comment: Exactly; you are not changing them independently. The derivative is precisely measuring the relative rates at which they go to zero. Just forget the fact it's on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a moment and consider $f(x) = x$. Now if I choose $u = 2$, what happens?

Comment: I get $2f^{'}(c)$ instead of $f^{'}(c)$? Or more like $f^{'}(c + h)$ +  $f^{'}(c)$.

Comment: Then I think the geometric intuition question to be asked here is this: "Do h and 2h goes to 0 at the same rate as $h \to 0$?" which turned out to be obvious I guess. So I was like asking something really apparent.